# Why is this particular piece of code exiting a quarter of the way through a run against a remote db, but not a local db?

Tags: node.js, debugging, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I wrote this script to pull a few s3 objects and import them into a database, when I run this against a local db it imports all 3265 records that I know should be there. When I run it against my AWS Postgres instance, it hangs a little part way through and exits cleanly and only imports about 50 or so records. I figured it was a timeout of some sort, but haven't been able to find anything to that effect. It also ignores the custom process.exit. I've combed through the Postgres instance logs too and nothing popped out at me there. I'm a little at a loss and I think I may just be missing a subtlety of node and or the way I wrote this code.

```
const { NODE_ENV } = process.env
import config from '../config'

config()

import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import db from './db/sequelize/models/db_connection'
process.on('uncaughtException', function (exception, p) {
  console.log(p)
  console.log(exception);
});

class FailedImport extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
    this.message = message;
  }
}

var s3 = new AWS.S3()
async function listObjects() {
  return await s3.listObjects({Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME}).promise()
}

function importData(objectList) {
  return objectList.Contents.map( async (obj) => {
    try {
      let data = await s3.getObject({ Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME, Key: obj.Key}).promise()
      let body = data.Body
      let dataLines = body.toString().split('\n')
      return Promise.all(dataLines.map( async (line) => {
        try {
          let jsonifiedLine = JSON.parse(line)
          return await db.Site.upsert({ url: jsonifiedLine['api_url'], quantcast_rank: 0})
        } catch(e) {
          console.error(e)
        }
      }))
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  })
}

export function runImport() {
  listObjects().then((objects) => {
    return Promise.all(importData(objects))
      .then(() => console.log('Finished import.'))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
    throw new FailedImport(err)
  })
}

runImport()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was mixing two very different styles of promise architecture and to top it off the way I was using map was not asynchronous safe. I wound up switching to for of for my loops and try catch async awaits and it fixed the code right up. New code below to compare:

```
class FailedImport extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
    this.message = message;
  }
}

var s3 = new AWS.S3()

async function listObjects() {
  return await s3.listObjects({Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME, Prefix: "datasets/cleaned.data/"}).promise()
}

async function importData(objectList) {
  try {
    for (let obj of objectList.Contents) {
      let data = await s3.getObject({ Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME, Key: obj.Key}).promise()
      console.log(obj.Key)
      let body = data.Body
      let dataLines = body.toString().split('\n')
      dataLines.pop()
      let jsonLines = dataLines.map((row) => JSON.parse(row.trim()))
      for (let line of jsonLines) {
        try {
          await db.Site.upsert({ url: line['api_url'], quantcast_rank: 0})
        }
        catch(err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

export function runImport() {
  listObjects().then((objects) => {
    importData(objects)
      .then(() => console.log('Finished.'))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err))
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  })
}
```